# Operations in C on binary file

Tags: c, file-io

I need to perform operations on a binary file such as edit a number of bytes at the beginning of the file or perform write operations jumping over "X times sizeof(int) areas". I am not interested in actual code snippets just what functions i should use, and if this is possible. Is this a job for fseek? It is important that i do not load any of the data from the file in my memory .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a job for `fseek()`.

Writing in the middle of a file will overwrite existing data. You need to move all subsequent data by the amount you intend to add.

Comment: And if I specify a certain offset in the middle it simply overwrites ?

Comment: @andrei yes - if you want to change a file's contents, you're better off creating a new file to which you write what is needed and rename (atomically) at the end. This is a common process, but which is full of pitfalls: google about this to find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fseek()`, but also have a look at `mmap()`. The advantage of a latter is that you don't have to care about the current pointer in the file, it is just a memory area you can navigate into using offsets.

Problem though: no `mmap()` for Windows. And if you want to *insert* data, it is not the best choice.

Comment: No problem, this is a linux application, if more efficient i shall use it

Comment: Well, `mmap()` has the advantage that you don't issue syscalls to read/write. BUT, if you want to insert data, though, it is not really suited, as @AdamZalcman rightly mentions.

Comment: I cannot find a documentation page for mmap() could you please link it? Is it included in a standard library ?

Comment: Yes it is standard, if you have man pages installed, `man mmap` should bring you the manpage. There are plenty of tutorials over the net too.

Comment: @andrei if you're worried about performance, better benchmark both implementation in your machine.